# How to add gradle tasks from a code correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy

I want to add few tasks depends on directory listing. I am using this code to achieve it:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated({
    def packagesDir = "${project.projectDir}/src/androidTest/java/com/site/myapp/mypackage"
    def dir = file(packagesDir)
    for (file in dir.listFiles()) {
        tasks.register(file.name) {
            group = 'report'
            description = "Collect info from " + file.name
            doLast {
                collectInfo(file.name)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This code successfully creates all needed tasks. But all of this tasks work as last. For example, directory contains:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
dir5
```

And when I launch `dir3` task or `dir4` (or any other) it works the same as `dir5` task (as if I launch `collectInfo(dir5)`).

How to add several gradle tasks from a code correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project (with Gradle 6.x) to create a series of gradle tasks per directory, I'm using smth like this:

```
List<File> frontEnds = file 'src/main/frontends' listFiles filter( { it.directory } as FileFilter )

frontEnds.each{ File f ->

    task "npmBuild-$f.name"( type:YarnTask ) {
        group = 'node'
        description = "Builds production version of $f.name frontend"
        workingDir = f
        args = [ 'build' ]
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried to remove doLast from my code but it doesn't help.

Comment: add `println file` to check into `doLast`

Comment: I'd say replace for-loop with `each`. that's gonna do the trick

Comment: You are right, it works with each. Thank you!